# Slick slider dots not changing color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using slick slider and website that I'm working on needs to have slider that have controls within slide content. I managed to append arrows into ".controls" div and then append dots between arrows buttons. At first it looked like everything is working fine but I noticed that dots are not behaving correctly. Only first slide have fully functioning dots that change color on slide change. How can I make dots in other slides to change color also?

How it looks:
First slide:
[dots color indicates first slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCPaZ.png)
Second slide:
[all dots on second slide are white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEQhb.png)

```
<div class="slick-slider">
<div class="slide">
    <div class="wrapper text">
        <h3></h3>
        <h4></h4>
        <p></p>
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="button" class="prev-slide"></button>
            <div class="dots"></div>
            <button type="button" class="next-slide"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slick-slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    appendDots: $('.dots'),
    prevArrow: $('.prev-slide'),
    nextArrow: $('.next-slide')
});
});
```

I can't figure out why dots in other slides don't have ".slick-active" class on them.

Comment: Try to make complete working exemple

Comment: could you please try to create a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers), that would help us to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not get complete HTML but the below solution may be helpful to you.

```
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before{
  color: orange
}
```

Comment: The problem is only first slide dots have ".slick-active" class on first dot. Dots on every other slide does not have it on any of their dots.

Answer (score 0):

try this once--

```
  .slick-dots button {
  display: block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: [i tried your snnipet hre](https://codepen.io/baonq/pen/LYVEyBm) see this snnipet paste your script here and remove ` appendDots: $('.kulki'),` than working fine

Comment: This is not solution. I need to have dots within every slide. That's why i have to use appendDots: $('.dots') setting in js.